# PHP in_array associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following $items PHP array...

```
Array (
    [44567] => Order_Item Object (
        [extra_data:protected] => Array (
        [product_id] => 0
        [variation_id] => 0
    )
    [data:protected] => Array (
        [order_id] => 4432
        [name] => Test Product
        [product_id] => 99
    )
    [cache_group:protected] => order-items
    [object_read:protected] => 1
    )
)
```

I am trying to use in_array to find out if it contains the product_id 99, I have tried...

```
if (in_array('99', $item['product_id'], true)) {
    echo 'DETECTED';
}
```

Does anybody have a similar working example I can look at?

Comment: You see the bit that says `Order_Item Object`.... that means it's an __object__ of type `Order_Item`, not an associative array.... so look at the methods available for that object

Comment: `1188` or `99`?

Comment: Edited op now, 1188 was typo :)